# Add Multiple Markers with Lat and Long from Sql server 2014

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I want to add 100 markers wtih Lat and Long from Sql server 2014
My markers don't show on the map. I dont know what is the problem.

Please help me improve my code or show me the better way to do it

this is my code

```java
public class Location {


    private String latlong_ID, latlong_nome;
    private Double latlong_Lat, latlong_Long;

    public Location(String latlong_ID, String latlong_nome,Double latlong_Lat,Double latlong_Long) {
        this.latlong_ID = latlong_ID;
        this.latlong_nome = latlong_nome;
        this.latlong_Lat = latlong_Lat;
        this.latlong_Long = latlong_Long;

    }

    public String getLatlong_ID() {
        return latlong_ID;
    }

    public void setLatlong_ID(String latlong_ID) {
        this.latlong_ID = latlong_ID;
    }

    public String getLatlong_nome() {
        return latlong_nome;
    }

    public void setLatlong_nome(String latlong_nome) {
        this.latlong_nome = latlong_nome;
    }

    public Double getLatlong_Lat() {
        return latlong_Lat;
    }

    public void setLatlong_Lat(Double latlong_Lat) {
        this.latlong_Lat = latlong_Lat;
    }

    public Double getLatlong_Long() {
        return latlong_Long;
    }

    public void setLatlong_Long(Double latlong_Long) {
        this.latlong_Long = latlong_Long;
    }
}


public class LocationLatLong extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String z = "";

       // List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < location.size() ; i++ ) {

                createMarker(location.get(i).getLatlong_Lat(),location.get(i).getLatlong_Long(),location.get(i).getLatlong_nome());

            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "select * from LojaLocation";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                    while (rs.next()) {

                        String LatLongID = rs.getString("Id");
                        String LatLongnome = rs.getString("Nome");
                        String LatLongLat = rs.getString("Latitude");
                        String LatLongLong = rs.getString("Longitudi");

                        Double LatLong_Lat1 = Double.valueOf(LatLongLat);
                        Double LatLong_Long1 = Double.valueOf(LatLongLong);




                        Location p = new Location(LatLongID, LatLongnome, LatLong_Lat1,LatLong_Long1 );

                        location.add(p);

                    }



                    z = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Error retrieving data from table";

            }
            return z;
        }
```

```java
protected void createMarker(Double latitude, Double longitude, String title) {

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
}
```

Comment: also add code of  createMarker(..) method

Comment: what is the value of `z` at end of method execution?

Comment: I use z to post comments

Comment: i did not ask what are you using z for, i asked what is the value of z

Comment: z is an empty variable of type String that i used as my feedback on each part of the code

Comment: i think that the erro is do way i retrieve the lat and long from Sql server

Answer (score 0):

do this on Map object to add Marker

```
LatLng latLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("You"));
```